# Checking for page templates in child theme

Tags: templates, child-theme, directory

I have a simple problem I'm hoping someone can shed some light on.  I have a child theme with a custom page template and I'm simply trying to check weather or not the template is in use.  Under normal circumstances, I would have just used the `is_page_template` function, however it doesn't seem to be working with child themes.  I've tried the following

```
if(is_page_template('template-custom-fullwidth.php')){
    //do something..
}
```

as well as

```
if(is_page_template(dirname(get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url')).'/template-custom-fullwidth.php'){
    //do something..
}
```

Neiter works and I was hoping there is a more elegant solution than using `$_SERVER` to check for URLs.  I can't imagine there not being a function for this seeing as this seems like a common task.  I believe the problem is the difference between template and stylesheet directories.  Is it possible to use Wordpress to check for page templates located in a child theme?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where are the files you checking this? is it possible that the page template uses a custom query which is not reset properly?

Comment: This does not work for me either. So far have not found any solution.